# NSDate constant for Fetch Predicate

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate

I'm using the Fetch Predicate in the IB to filter our the default result return from Core Data and I'm actually looking for some like this:

dateCreated < YESTERDAY

where "YESTERDAY" is supposed to be a nsdate constant for yesterday so that all my result return is before yesterday.

This didn't work. And some searching didn't turn up anything related to this so I'm wondering what I want to do here is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of Core Data (because this really has nothing to do with Core Data, only [predicates](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798)), your query itself (before a certain date) is perfectly normal, but the predicate syntax has no facilities for "natural language" dates.

You pass in a date object and that's that. It's up to you to [create an appropriate date object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) to represent "yesterday".

To get the same sort of "automatic" behavior you're looking for, you could bind your array controller's fetch predicate to some controller via some key (KVC-compliant method) like "beforeYesterdayPredicate" ... this method would hand back a dynamically-generated predicate that you'd create with code.